# Javascript Performance Optimization

Tags: javascript, performance

I am using the code below that loops around thousands of time, I need this to be as fast as possible, however I am not an expert in Javascript and all I know is that this code is faster than doing it with the `innerHTML` method.

Can it be optimized? If so, how?

```
    var a,b,c,d,e,
    trEl, tdEl, imgEl

    for (i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
      trEl = document.createElement('tr');
      tdEl = document.createElement('td');
      td1El = document.createElement('td');
      td2El = document.createElement('td');
      td3El = document.createElement('td');
      imgEl = document.createElement('img');

      var str
      a = docs[i]['a']
      b = docs[i]['b']
      c = docs[i]['c']
      d = docs[i]['date'] + " - " + docs[i]['timestamp']
      e = docs[i]['_e']

      trEl.setAttribute('id', e);
      trEl.setAttribute('ondblclick', 'scan(' + '"' + e + '"' + ')');
      imgEl.setAttribute('src', 'css/bullet.png');
      tdEl.appendChild(imgEl);

      tdEl.appendChild(document.createTextNode(a));
      td1El.appendChild(document.createTextNode(d));
      td2El.appendChild(document.createTextNode(b));
      td3El.appendChild(document.createTextNode(c));

      trEl.appendChild(tdEl);
      trEl.appendChild(td1El);
      trEl.appendChild(td2El);
      trEl.appendChild(td3El);

      document.getElementById("search-results").appendChild(trEl)
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't evaluate `docs.length` in every iteration - it's constant so it only needs to be evaluated once:

```
for (var i = 0, n = docs.length; i < n; ++i)
```

Deference `docs[i]` into an aliased variable so that you're not repeatedly doing an array lookup into the same element, and don't use strings for keys unless the key is variable:

```
var doc = docs[i];
var a = doc.a;
...
```

If the above local variables `a` through `e` are only used once, don't bother storing them at all, just put them in as trivial parameters when needed (see below)

Use DOM properties instead of `setAttribute` function calls when you can:

```
trEl.id = doc._e;                // instead of 'e'
imgEl.src = 'css/bullet.png';
```

Don't use inline event handlers:

```
trEl.addEventListener('dblclick', scan, false);
```

There's no need to pass the variable `e` to `scan` since it's just the clicked element's ID and therefore trivially extracted within the event handler:

```
function scan(event) {
    var e = this.id;
    ...
}
```

Use a `DocumentFragment` to store all of the new elements, and then add the entire fragment into the `document` in one go, allowing the browser to handle all of the visible DOM changes in one hit:

```
var rows = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (...) {
    ...
    rows.appendChild(trEl);
}

document.getElementById("search-results").appendChild(rows);
```

Comment: @FiatPax I'd be interested to hear how much performance gain you achieve

Comment: Here is the report from benchmark.js "optimized x 101,487 ops/sec ±6.66% (56 runs sampled), old x 64,893 ops/sec ±11.52% (64 runs sampled) Fastest is optimized."

Comment: I applied all of the methods above except one with event listeners, because if I add trEl.addEventListener('dblclick', scan, false); it will complain its undefined. I'm not sure where to add that code.

Comment: That'll depend on where (and how) you've declared the `scan` function.

Comment: or is it complaining about `addEventListener` being undefined (older MSIE versions), in which case you could just do `trEl.ondblclick = scan`

Comment: Ahh, now its okay, I wasn't adding it into for loop, I added there and now it works too. Thanks!